Am I missing much by reading Gelfand and Fomin's Calculus of Variations?
Gelfand and Fomin seems to be the most recommended text for an introduction into the Calculus of Variations. That being said, there are a couple of reasons as to why I worry this may not be the best choice for me:

The book was written in 1963, and is thus perhaps missing new results or approaches.

As the book states on its second page, its main concern are functionals of the form
$$y\mapsto \int F(x, y, y') \ \text{d}x,$$
and I may thus miss on the more 'general' theory of variations.


I was hoping someone could tell me whether my concerns are warranted and I should choose a different book, or whether the text is as modern and general as other sources and I should stick with it.
Perhaps I should also mention that I am interested both in the mathematics and physics relating to the topic.
